# Can some cryptographic conclusions in the prime field be applied to the Galois field？

Tags: discrete-logarithm, finite-field, group-theory, factoring

Such as integer factorization problem and discrete logarithm problem. Assuming a large polynomial is obtained by multiplying two generated polynomials, is it NP hard to decompose it into these two generated polynomials ? And Assuming that A is the generator of the Galois field and B is a random number, is it NP hard to find an x to make $A^x=B$ hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the integer Discrete Log (DL) is not known to be NP complete. As pointed out in the comment by @poncho, $NP\neq coNP$ which may well be the case would imply that DL is not NP-hard.

Its exact hardness is unknown. And of course the Merkle-Hellman knapsack public key cryptosystem was based on an NP-hard problem but it was broken.

Regarding the finite field DL (see the detailed answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48767/the-computational-complexity-of-discrete-log)): for some settings its complexity is quasi polynomial, otherwise it can be subexponential but superpolynomial.

For characteristic 2, see this question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/56215/complexity-of-discrete-logarithms-in-binary-fields-without-special-exponents-or).

For polynomial factorization over finite fields there is  [Berlekamp's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm),  and its later improvements.

Comment: Actually $NP \ne coNP$ (which appears likely) would imply that DL is *not* NP hard...